# AsyncTask infinite loop

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am retrieving some data from a JSON API in the `doInBackground()` when my program is in `doInBackground()` method my Log indicates that the data is retrieved, but instead of going to `onPostExecute()` the `doInBackground()` is still running in an infinite loop.
How can I stop that loop?

This is my `doInBackground()` coding:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... DATA) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TYPE = DATA[0];

if(TYPE=="reservation_page")
    {
        URL = DATA[1];
        jParser = new JsonParser();
        json = jParser.getJSONfromUrl(URL+memberId);
        try
        {
            JSONArray reservation = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RSVTION);
            for(int i = 0; i<reservation.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject r = reservation.getJSONObject(i);
                amount = r.getString(TAG_AMNT);
                gcpamount = r.getString(TAG_GCPAMNT);
                date1 = r.getString(TAG_DATE);
                month = r.getString(TAG_MNTH);
                year = r.getString(TAG_YEAR);
                time1 = r.getString(TAG_TIME);
                golfcourse_name = r.getString(TAG_GLFCRSNAME);
                no_of_player = r.getString(TAG_PLYRNO);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_AMNT, amount);
                map.put(TAG_GCPAMNT, gcpamount);
                map.put(TAG_DATE, date1);
                map.put(TAG_MNTH, month);
                map.put(TAG_YEAR, year);
                map.put(TAG_TIME, time1);
                map.put(TAG_GLFCRSNAME, golfcourse_name);
                map.put(TAG_PLYRNO, no_of_player);

                resvList.add(map);
                Log.v(TAG_LOG, "list: "+resvList);
            }
            Log.v(LoadingScreen.TAG_LOG, "reserv: "+reservation);
            Log.v(LoadingScreen.TAG_LOG, "name: "+golfcourse_name);
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Log.v(LoadingScreen.TAG_LOG, String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is my `onPostExecute()` coding:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

if(TYPE=="reservation_page")
    {
        Intent in = new Intent(context, MyReservation.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_MBRID, memberId);
        in.putExtra(TAG_AMNT, amount);
        in.putExtra(TAG_GCPAMNT, gcpamount);
        in.putExtra(TAG_DATE, date1);
        in.putExtra(TAG_DAY, day);
        in.putExtra(TAG_MNTH, month);
        in.putExtra(TAG_YEAR, year);
        in.putExtra(TAG_TIME, time1);
        in.putExtra(TAG_GLFCRSNAME, golfcourse_name);
        in.putExtra(TAG_PLYRNO, no_of_player);
        context.startActivity(in);
    }
    progress.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, only one loop in the doInBackground method.  What are the typical values of reservation.length() ?

Comment: I'd suggest you Log.i() your length() and int i in the loop and see what happens in there.

Comment: Put a breakpoint after you exit from the loop in doInbackground and another one in onPostExecute and you shall soon find out I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blah....Blah... Blah...

Your **if condition is wrong**.. It should be like,

```
if(TYPE.equals("reservation_page"))
```

Not

```
if(TYPE=="reservation_page")
```

Use `.equals()` of `String Class` to compare two strings..

Answer (score 1):

Are you even entering the loop or does perhaps `jParser.getJSONfromUrl(URL+memberId)` wait forever for a response form your URL? Just run your debugger, it should'nt be a problem to find out what's wrong.

Comment: i have many if statements in my doInBackground() rest of the if statements are working fine only this one is login in loop..